# how to pass the model class data to hasmap?

Tags: android

My Question is as I put the provided data into ArrayList<>..
using the line cityDataItemList.add(cityDataItem);
similarly, how can I put the same data into hashmap object?

```
public class SampleDataProvider {

    public static List<CityDataItem> cityDataItemList;
    public static Map<String,CityDataItem> dataItemMap;
    static
    {
    cityDataItemList=new ArrayList<>();
    dataItemMap=new HashMap<>();
       addItem(new CityDataItem(null,"Lahore",2,
                "Punjab",15000000,
                "Lahore is 2nd Largest City of Pakistan ",
                "lahore.jpg"));
        addItem(new CityDataItem(null,"Islamabad",3,
                "Capital Terrortory",15000000,
                "Islamabad is a DarulHakumt of Paksitan",
                "islamabad.jpg"));

}

private static void addItem(CityDataItem cityDataItem) {

        cityDataItemList.add(cityDataItem);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you can do,

```
dataItemMap.put("your_key",new CityDataItem(null,"Islamabad",3,
            "Capital Terrortory",15000000,
            "Islamabad is a DarulHakumt of Paksitan",
            "islamabad.jpg"));
```

`HashMap` provides `put()` method to insert items according to **Key-Value** pair, in the above

```
put("your_key",new CityDataItem(null,"Islamabad",3,
            "Capital Terrortory",15000000,
            "Islamabad is a DarulHakumt of Paksitan",
            "islamabad.jpg"));
```

`your_key` is the **Key Part** and the rest `new CityDataItem(null,"Islamabad",3,
                "Capital Terrortory",15000000,
                "Islamabad is a DarulHakumt of Paksitan",
                "islamabad.jpg"));` is the **Value Part**.

You define the type of **Key Value** when you declare the `HashMap` variable.For ex
the line `public static Map<String,CityDataItem> dataItemMap;` signifies that variable `dataItemMap` will consist of two parts,

1. A **Key** -  which will be a type of `String`.
2. A **Value** - which will be a type of `CityDataItem`.

You can later extract items from `HashMap` using the `get()` method.
To extract an already added value, we just need the **Key** to extract the **Value**,like this `hashMapObj.get("my_key")` and you will have the **Value** which was stored for the provided corresponding **Key**.